# Why new Date('DD-MM-YYYY') in react native is returning wrong date?

Tags: react-native, date

I am using dayjs and I have an input field where user can enter a date or choose one from the picker, if I am using DD-MM-YYYY format there is an issue that at first I thought it's only happening with dayjs but when I tested with the native Date() same issue happening
I tried doing
`console.log(new Date('01-01-2023'));` and this is showing `0006-07-16T02:00:00+02:00`

If I use the YYYY-MM-DD format it is working but I don't understand what could be causing this issue. It is happening both on android and iOS

Running `npx react-native info`:

```
System:
  OS: macOS 14.2
  CPU: (12) arm64 Apple M2 Max
  Memory: 77.72 MB / 32.00 GB
  Shell:
    version: "5.9"
    path: /bin/zsh
Binaries:
  Node:
    version: 20.10.0
    path: /usr/local/bin/node
  Yarn:
    version: 4.0.2
    path: ~/.nvm/versions/node/v20.10.0/bin/yarn
  npm:
    version: 10.2.3
    path: ~/.nvm/versions/node/v20.10.0/bin/npm
  Watchman:
    version: 2023.12.04.00
    path: /opt/homebrew/bin/watchman
Managers:
  CocoaPods:
    version: 1.14.3
    path: /Users/myuser/.rbenv/shims/pod
SDKs:
  iOS SDK:
    Platforms:
      - DriverKit 23.2
      - iOS 17.2
      - macOS 14.2
      - tvOS 17.2
      - watchOS 10.2
  Android SDK:
    Android NDK: 22.1.7171670
IDEs:
  Android Studio: 2023.1 AI-231.9392.1.2311.11076708
  Xcode:
    version: 15.1/15C65
    path: /usr/bin/xcodebuild
Languages:
  Java:
    version: 17.0.9
    path: /usr/bin/javac
  Ruby:
    version: 2.6.10
    path: /usr/bin/ruby
npmPackages:
  "@react-native-community/cli": Not Found
  react:
    installed: 18.2.0
    wanted: 18.2.0
  react-native:
    installed: 0.72.3
    wanted: 0.72.3
  react-native-macos: Not Found
npmGlobalPackages:
  "*react-native*": Not Found
Android:
  hermesEnabled: true
  newArchEnabled: false
iOS:
  hermesEnabled: true
  newArchEnabled: false
```

Comment: Because you can _only_ use YYYY-MM-DD, so what you did is specifying January 2023rd, 0001 which unrolls to July 16th, 0006 (2022 days after January 1st, 0001). For other formats, parse them yourself and use the date constructor that takes individual values for year, month and day.

Answer (score 1):

A simple answer might be to just convert the format yourself when you detect it.

```js
// super basic but effective enough
function dateIsDDMMYYYY(dateString) {
  const third = dateString.split("-")[2]
  return third.length === 4
}
```

Once you detect that it is in DDMMYYYY format, try this to swap it:

```js
const newDateString = myDateString.split("-").reverse().join("-");
```

Now it's in YYYY-MM-DD format, and you can parse your date accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

```
const currentDate = new Date();
       const GivenDate = new Date(baseStore.scooterListByID.createdOn);
       const differenceInTime = currentDate.getTime() - GivenDate.getTime();
       const differenceInDays = Math.round(differenceInTime / (1000 * 3600 * 24));
```

For example, in the code above, I converted two dates to milliseconds with **getTime()**. Then I made divisions for the necessary mathematical operations. Apart from that, I did some research for the question you asked. The solution could be:

`console.log(new Date('January 01,2023))` or `console.log(new Date(2023,1,1))` If you write it this way, I hope it will yield results.

Comment: I already mentioned that using the YYYY-MM-DD format it is working as expected but now I have to force the users to always write dates in this format

Comment: Or you parse the format yourself. Also, you need to specify the format the users have to use anyway because formats are ambiguous and you can't autodetect them - besides DD-MM-YYYY there is also MM-DD-YYYY and you can't know which is which if the day month is below 13 (e.g. 06-08-2000 could be either June 8th or August 6th).